# Evaluating a defined integral with a square root (expanding required)

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

a) Expand $(4\sqrt{x} +3)^2$

b) Hence evaluate :

$$\int_0^3(4\sqrt{x} +3)^2dx$$

Giving your answer in the form of $a+b\sqrt{3}$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers.

---

Hello all. Having a bit of trouble with this one.
By expanding I have come to $57+24\sqrt{3}$.
Is this right?

How am I able to evaluate the defined integral with the square root and power?

Is it the same as usual?

Comment: I edited your question to use MathJax. Is the expression supposed to be $4\sqrt{x} + 3$, or $4\sqrt{x + 3}$?

Comment: I know we can also rewrite this as (4x^-1/2 +3) (4x^-1/2 +3) and then multiply out. Would this be the best method?

Comment: Thanks Dylan that's very helpful. It's the first of the two.

Comment: Following my comment that would lead to 16x right?

Comment: Once a question has been answered, don't deface it. Rather, consider accepting one of the answers, if any of them meets your standard of quality.

Answer (score 3):

$$(4\sqrt{x}+3)(4\sqrt{x}+3)=16x+24\sqrt{x}+9$$
Hence
\begin{align}
\int \limits_0^3 (16x+24\sqrt{x}+9) dx &= \left(8x^{2}+16\sqrt{x^{3}}+9x\right)\Biggr \rvert_0^3 \\
                                     &= 8(3)^{2}+16\sqrt{3^3}+9(3) \\
                                     &= 8(9)+16\sqrt{27}+27 \\
                                     &= 99+48\sqrt{3}
\end{align}

Comment: Sarah, By using the calculator to integrate, your answer does not come up right, Bacon's does (182....etc)

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance everybody I can now see where I was wrong and have rectified this!

Comment: Thank you Bacon et al, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

- $$(ax+b)^2=(ax+b)(ax+b)=axax+axb+axb+bb=(ax)^2+b^2+2axb$$

  ---

Assume $b>a$ and $a,b,r,t\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\int_{a}^{b}\left(r\sqrt{x}+t\right)^2\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int_{a}^{b}\left(r\sqrt{x}+t\right)\left(r\sqrt{x}+t\right)\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int_{a}^{b}\left(r\sqrt{x}r\sqrt{x}+r\sqrt{x}t+r\sqrt{x}t+tt\right)\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int_{a}^{b}\left(r^2x+t^2+2rt\sqrt{x}\right)\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int_{a}^{b}r^2x\space\text{d}x+\int_{a}^{b}t^2\space\text{d}x+\int_{a}^{b}2rt\sqrt{x}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$r^2\int_{a}^{b}x\space\text{d}x+t^2\int_{a}^{b}1\space\text{d}x+2rt\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{x}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$r^2\left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_{a}^{b}+t^2\left[x\right]_{a}^{b}+2rt\left[\frac{2x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}\right]_{a}^{b}=$$
$$\frac{r^2}{2}\left[x^2\right]_{a}^{b}+t^2\left[x\right]_{a}^{b}+\frac{4rt}{3}\left[x^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_{a}^{b}=$$
$$\frac{r^2\left(b^2-a^2\right)}{2}+t^2(b-a)+\frac{4rt\left(b^{\frac{3}{2}}-a^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)}{3}$$

---

Now, set $a=0,b=3,r=4,t=3$:

$$\frac{4^2\left(3^2-0^2\right)}{2}+3^2(3-0)+\frac{4\cdot4\cdot3\left(3^{\frac{3}{2}}-0^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)}{3}=$$
$$\frac{144}{2}+27+\frac{48\left(3^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)}{3}=$$
$$72+27+16\left(3^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)=$$
$$99+16\cdot3\sqrt{3}=$$
$$99+48\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: ...As explained much more concisely in another answer posted 2 hours earlier.